# How do I use log parser(logpai) on Linux logs

Tags: parsing, logging, artificial-intelligence

I'm using [LogPai](https://github.com/logpai/logparser) logparser  to parse unstructured logs into a csv file for my project right now and I can't figure out how to parse Linux logs properly.
Their demo on the github shows how to parse HDFS logs, and I was trying to infer on how to parse linux logs from it. I've read the docs to check if they show this anywhere but unfortunately not.

My current problem is that the logformat has the Component and PID right next to each other, so when I parse it, the csv file fucks up the labeling. Plus the Pid is in [] which is another thing I'm not sure on how to check for.

I've tried using this log_format

```
log_format = '<Month> <Date> <Time> <Level> <Component><Pid>: <Content>'
```

which managed to get me very close, however, now it puts both the component and the pid into the PID column, thus leaving the component column empty. Any idea how I can fix this if there is anyone using LogPAI on here?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm using the drain algorithm to try and parse the file.

Comment: I suggest you to process each line of log file beforehand by putting  a space between component and pid; for line in file: formatted_line = ' ['.join(line.split('[', 1)); save this to a new file and parse

Answer (score 1):

There is sample `log_format` present in the repo under `benchmark` maybe that helps

https://github.com/logpai/logparser/blob/0421747e86f47ebc59df69d2c9951f429538d93d/benchmark/Drain_benchmark.py#L78-L84

```
    'Linux': {
        'log_file': 'Linux/Linux_2k.log',
        'log_format': '<Month> <Date> <Time> <Level> <Component>(\[<PID>\])?: <Content>',
        'regex': [r'(\d+\.){3}\d+', r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'],
        'st': 0.39,
        'depth': 6        
        },
```